# Identify Toshiba CRT

Tags: crt-monitor, identify-this-peripheral

Didn't find anything with a search and need to replace the tube due to it being severely burnt in.

[image: CRT label]

[image: More CRT label]

Comment: Adding a front view picture could be useful too.

Comment: I literally just googled 'Toshiba LR30477' and the first thing that came up https://www.radwell.co.uk/Buy/TOSHIBA/TOSHIBA/LR30477?redirect=true

Comment: Where was this CRT used? Toshiba LR30477 CRT was quite common, but no longer in production. You should get a refurbished one or a replacement.  Try searching for LR30477 or Fanuc CRT A61L-0001

Comment: You are aware that CRTs are driven with several kilovolts at low current capacity (which can hurt) and also several hundred volts at (depending on the exact circuitry) much higher current capacity (which can GET YOU hurt), and that monitor power supplies can sometimes have remaining stored energy even with the device unpowered, and that CRTs itself are big capacitors that can be charged to the several kilovolts, and also are an implosion (read: flying glass) hazard if accidentally ruptured (dropped or punctured) the wrong way?

Comment: @rackandboneman yeah I discharged the caps/tube and trust myself enough to not die